# SVProgressHUD not animating when enter to foreground from Background

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, animation, svprogresshud

I'm facing the SVProgressHUD animation (hud animation not working. just showing the hud without spinning animation) issue when I enter the background and stay for 5 or more seconds and again enter into the foreground. Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: you are showing SVProgressHUD on Window or on a view?

Comment: You can try [MKProgress](https://github.com/kamirana4/MKProgress) that works well when you resume from the background.

Answer (score 0):

in which thread you are doing that start animation .. providing the code will be better understandable for users

Comment: installed SVProgressHUD pod. And here is code
`SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)
 SVProgressHUD.setDefaultAnimationType(.native)
 SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(AppColors.headerColor)
 SVProgressHUD.show(withMessage: Messages.kProgressRetrieving)`.

Comment: after that, I'm calling API to get some info from DB.

Comment: SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "message") ....... provide full code .. in which thread u are using this

Comment: then make a function for showing HUD . make them in main thread . hide them also in the same . way                                                             func showHUD(with message : Striing)->Void
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SVProgressHUD.show(withMessage: message)
        }
    }